# Castle Windsor ChildContainer Dependency Resolution

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am using Castle Windsor and here is what i want to do.

`ParentContainer` has `CarFactory` depending on abstract `WheelFactory` but `WheelFactory` would be registered in child containers 1 and 2

`ChildContainer 1` has `WheelFactory` as `BigWheelFactory`
`ChildContainer 2` has `WheelFactory` as `SmallWheelFactory`

Now we have `[ParentContainer (ChildContainer 1, ChildContainer 2)]`

**Thread 1** uses only `ChildContainer 1`

**Thread 2** uses only `ChildContainer 2`

**Thread 1** ask for `CarFactory` from `ChildContainer 1`, car factory should use `BigWheelFactory` in this case.

**Thread 2** ask for `CarFactory` from `ChildContainer 2`, car factory should use `SmallWheelFactory` in this case.

how can i achieve this with Castle Windsor. Even if means not using child containers

Comment: If by "process", you are referring to [executable processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841(v=vs.85).aspx), each should have their own DI configuration that is completely separate from the other processes. While it is possible to serialize objects to send them from one process to another, that is a runtime design feature of an application, not something that pertains to DI, which is only for composing applications. If that is not what you mean by process, I suggest you change your question to clarify your actual meaning.

Comment: @NightOwl888 suggestion acknowledged. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of child container try standard service override:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(Component.For<HostForThread1>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey<CarFactory>().Is("CarFactory1")));
container.Register(Component.For<HostForThread2>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey<CarFactory>().Is("CarFactory2")));

container.Register(Component.For<CarFactory>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey<WheelFactory>().Is<BigWheelFactory>()).Named("CarFactory1"));
container.Register(Component.For<CarFactory>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey<WheelFactory>().Is<SmallWheelFactory>()).Named("CarFactory2"));

container.Register(Component.For<WheelFactory>().ImplementedBy<BigWheelFactory>());
container.Register(Component.For<WheelFactory>().ImplementedBy<SmallWheelFactory>());


public class HostForThread1
{
    public HostForThread1(CarFactory factory)
    {
        this.Factory = factory;
    }

    public CarFactory Factory { get; }
}

public class HostForThread2
{
    public HostForThread2(CarFactory factory)
    {
        this.Factory = factory;
    }

    public CarFactory Factory { get; }
}

public class CarFactory
{
    public CarFactory(WheelFactory wheelFactory)
    {
        this.WheelFactory = wheelFactory;
    }

    public WheelFactory WheelFactory { get; }
}

public abstract class WheelFactory
{
}

public class BigWheelFactory : WheelFactory
{
}

public class SmallWheelFactory : WheelFactory
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, i mentioned thread 1 and 2 for simplicity but this could be N number of threads and i guess this wont scale. My exact use case is for Service fabric actors where i want to have all common registrations and some per actor. This is because in service fabric i could not find any way of getting a reference of current executing actor (just like HttpContext.Current). basically i need some dependencies per actor scope and i can only do it if i had a container per actor with a parent container for common stuff.

Comment: @Gurpreet Maybe this would be interesting for you: https://github.com/keithbo/Castle.Facilities.ServiceFabricIntegration. Anyway child containers are not recommended to use with Castle and this particular example doesn't work as expected with them. So you must find another solution, either service override or implementing own HandlersSelector or maybe even something else.